# RecyclerView not refreshed automatically with submitList() and LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-diffutils

here is the situation:

I have a `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment` using `DataBinding`. Its adapter is a `ListAdapter`.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(...) {
        val binding = // inflate layout with DataBindingUtil

        val myListAdapter = MyListAdapter()
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = myListAdapter

        val myViewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
        myViewModel.myLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            println("before submit: ${myListAdapter.currentList}")
            myListAdapter.submitList(it)
            println("after submit: ${myListAdapter.currentList}")
        })

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Data to display is represented by a `List<Double>`. Once set, the list is used to initialize a `MutableLiveData` as follows:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val data = listOf<Double>(/* init with some values */)
    val myLiveData = MutableLiveData(data)

    fun onButtonClicked() {
        update()
        println(myLiveData.value) // LiveData is correctly updated according to data
    }
}
```

> Note: the `update()` method changes the list's values like: `data[0] = someValue`. It does not use `clear()` nor `addAll()` to update it.

- In addition, I override `ListAdapter.onCurrentListChanged()` only to put a `println()` inside.

At this point, nothing peculiar. When the fragment is created, the `RecyclerView` shows the initial list. In Logcat:

```
I/System.out: before submit: []
I/System.out: onCurrentListChanged: [] -> [4.07, 6.29, 13.85, 17.92, 21.42, 23.47, 1.85]
I/System.out: after submit: [4.07, 6.29, 13.85, 17.92, 21.42, 23.47, 1.85]
```

For now, when I click on the button, the UI does not refresh because I did not assign a new list but only update the current one. Besides, if I navigate to another fragment then come back, the `RecyclerView`
is displaying the updated values.

So I add the following at the end of `onButtonClicked()`:

```
myLiveData.value = myLiveData.value
```

But this does not work, after clicking on the button the UI is still not updating automatically. Moreover, the Logcat prints only the 'before submit' and 'after submit', with the same `ListAdapter.currentList` value:

```
I/System.out: before submit: [4.88, 6.77, 13.85, 17.76, 20.93, 22.69, 1.85]
I/System.out: after submit: [4.88, 6.77, 13.85, 17.76, 20.93, 22.69, 1.85]
```

To me, prints should rather look like this:

```
I/System.out: before submit: [4.07, 6.29, 13.85, 17.92, 21.42, 23.47, 1.85]
I/System.out: onCurrentListChanged: [4.07, 6.29, 13.85, 17.92, 21.42, 23.47, 1.85] -> [4.88, 6.77, 13.85, 17.76, 20.93, 22.69, 1.85]
I/System.out: after submit: [4.88, 6.77, 13.85, 17.76, 20.93, 22.69, 1.85]
```

It appears that `ListAdapter.currentList` has already the updated value even before calling `submitList()`. I guess this is why the `RecyclerView` is not refreshed since the submitted list is the same as the current one.
I also tried the following at the end of `onButtonClicked()` with no success:

```
//myLiveData.value = myLiveData.value
myLiveData.value = emptyList()
myLiveData.value = data
```

And this...

```
//myLiveData.value = myLiveData.value
myLiveData.value = emptyList()
//myLiveData.value = data
```

... gives me that:

```
I/System.out: before submit: [4.88, 6.77, 13.85, 17.76, 20.93, 22.69, 1.85]
I/System.out: after submit: [4.88, 6.77, 13.85, 17.76, 20.93, 22.69, 1.85]
I/System.out: onCurrentListChanged: [4.88, 6.77, 13.85, 17.76, 20.93, 22.69, 1.85] -> []
```

Now `onCurrentListChanged()` is called but at the end of the 2 prints instead of in the middle.
Also, `ListAdapter.currentList` seems to contain values in the 'after submit' prints but is actually empty in the `onCurrentListChanged()` print. Confusing...

The only way I found to make the `RecyclerView` refresh is to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. But then, there is no benefit to use `ListAdapter` and its `submitList()` method.

As a newbie, I may have done something not correctly but I do not know what.
The problem is only about the UI not refreshing. I can see in Locgcat that data is properly updating.

Thanks in advance

## EDIT

```
class MyListAdapter() : ListAdapter<Double, MyViewHolder>(MyDiffCallBack()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        MyViewHolder.from(parent, itemCount)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) =
        holder.bind(getItem(position))

    override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: MutableList<Double>, currentList: MutableList<Double>) {
        super.onCurrentListChanged(previousList, currentList)
        println("onCurrentListChanged: $previousList -> $currentList")
    }
}

class MyViewHolder private constructor(private val binding: MyItemViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(data: Double) {
        binding.dataTxt.text = data.toString()
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup, itemCount: Int): MyViewHolder {
            val binding = // inflate layout
            binding.root.layoutParams.height = parent.height / itemCount // set the height proportionally
            return MyViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}

class MyDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Double>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Double, newItem: Double): Boolean = oldItem == newItem

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Double, newItem: Double): Boolean = oldItem == newItem

}
```

Comment: Could you share the minimal representation of your recycler view adapter code?

Comment: Are you using `DiffUtil` callback correctly?

Comment: @MosheRabaev I guess, I have edited my question by adding the Adapter/Holder/DiffUtil classes.

Comment: In your `areItemsTheSame`, try changing `oldItem == newItem` to `oldItem.id == newItem.id`

Comment: @ThunderCock But items are Double values. How can I do it ?

Comment: `val myViewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()` should be field

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Why that? I mean, if I use myViewModel only inside onCreateView, I can just make it a local variable. Or will the ViewModel not work properly? In any case, this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Same is happening with me
After updating a **single Item** in LiveData List
The adapter's list's contents are updated but the actual view is NOT

Comment: I am having the same issue with live data, I tried to convert it into a list and still not working. Did anybody else solve this?

Comment: @VictorCocuz did not the answer work for you?

Comment: In the end copying the list before submitting it to the adapter worked for me. I created a function like this: fun MutableList<Object>.getCopiedList(): MutableList<Object> {
    val list = mutableListOf<Object>()
    this.forEach {
            list.add(it.copy())
    }
    return list
}

Comment: Can any body tell me in Java code how to create copy before submitList?

Comment: @SaiprasadPrabhu did you solve , it?

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli Nope :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a problem related to the difference between shallow and deep copies.
As stated in this [article](https://hackathon-blog-42.medium.com/listadapter-renewed-9b5b496198e2) about `ListAdapter`:

> Good to know is that the `ListAdapter` **keeps a reference** towards the provided list in `submitList()`. Always make sure to provide an other list with **other item instances**. If the references to the items are the same, `DiffUtil` compares the same items which are always equal, and the `RecyclerView` **will not be updated**.

Comment: Do you make a deep copy and assign it?

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli Every time I provide a list to `submitList()`, all of its items are newly created. This way, the references are not same.